# Warning: React does not recognize the `warnKey` prop on a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am using testing-library/react for routing unit test below is my code
my test cases getting passed but I am getting console error for

***React does not recognize the `warnKey` prop on a DOM element.***

Any Idea ? below is my code and error screenshot

```
import {render, screen} from '@testing-library/react'
import {createMemoryHistory} from 'history'
import React from 'react'
import {Router} from 'react-router-dom'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'

import AdminPanel from './AdminPanel'

test('full app rendering/navigating',async () => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory()
  
  render(
    <Router history={history}>
      <AdminPanel />
    </Router>,
  )
  let title = await screen.findByText(/Admin Portal/i)
  expect(title).toBeInTheDocument()

})
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [styled component error "it looks like an unknown prop "responsive" is sent through to the DOM, which will likely trigger a React console error."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76857070/styled-component-error-it-looks-like-an-unknown-prop-responsive-is-sent-throu)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check [Unknown Prop Warning](https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html):

> The unknown-prop warning will fire if you attempt to render a DOM element with a prop that is not recognized by React as a legal DOM attribute/property. You should ensure that your DOM elements do not have spurious props floating around.

> You are using a non-standard DOM attribute on a native DOM node, perhaps to represent custom data

E.g.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';

const MenuItemGroup = (props) => <div {...props}>Admin Portal</div>;

export default function AdminPanel() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MenuItemGroup warnKey={1} className="menu-item-group" />
    </div>
  );
}

test('full app rendering/navigating', async () => {
  render(<AdminPanel />);
  expect(screen.findByText(/Admin Portal/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

`warnKey` is not a standard DOM attribute, we pass it directly to the div element, which will trigger the above warning. The solution is to destructure our custom non-standard attributes from props and pass the standard DOM attributes such as `className`, `role`, `id` to the target element through the spread operator.

For more standard HTML attributes, you can check [All Supported HTML Attributes](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#all-supported-html-attributes)

```
const MenuItemGroup = ({ warnKey, ...rest }) => {
  // Use your custom props `warnKey`
  
  // `rest` props are all standard DOM attributes.
  return <div {...rest}>Admin Portal</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check all the places where you are passing props and just see if there is some irrelevant prop which is being passed and is not needed by the component.

In the code snippet, you have attached I can just see the history prop, check in the file where the error is showing up.