# styled component error "it looks like an unknown prop "responsive" is sent through to the DOM, which will likely trigger a React console error."

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-props, react-data-table-component, dom-element

I am using react data table component which requires me to install styled component.

The moment i render the DataTable after passing the columns and data prop, I get various errors on my console saying there is a problem with some of the props im using such as the isActive. Meanwhile, I am actually not using that prop anywhere in my code

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5VmD.png)

[My code where I am using the data table component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9IzM.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: FWIW I am also seeing this. Would be nice if the question was updated to include the error and code sample

Answer (score 3):

This is a breaking change from a dependency of react-data-table-component, styled-components [version 6](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/releases/tag/v6.0.0)

The react-data-table-component library will need to be updated to properly use styled-components 6. For now, I solved this by downgrading styled-components to version 5:

`npm install styled-components@5`

Comment: This isn't a solution for fixing this issue. It would only avoid facing this message.

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing the same issue and there are a few workarounds out there to make it work, one of these is the one mentioned above (downgrading the package), however, in my case what worked out was:

[image: Migration Guide from the Official website]

I added the **shouldForwardProp** provided in the migration guide in my helpers file, then I exported it, and voila!

I guess the migration guide is pretty straightforward, at least it worked on my case, hope it helps guys!

**[Migration Guide v6](https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#what-do-i-need-to-do-to-migrate-to-v6)**

Regards

Comment: I tried this but am still getting the warnings. I am using Next JS 14 with app routing and styled-components@v6.1.8

Answer (score 0):

You need to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@emotion/is-prop-valid

then try to use such a wrapper:

```
<StyleSheetManager shouldForwardProp={shouldForwardProp}>
    <App />
</StyleSheetManager>
```

And then – the shouldForwardProp realisation from previous answer or similar.